# Vim - automatically delete SWP file after recovery doesn't change the original file

Tags: vim, gvim

When the Vim process is abruptly terminated (e.g. system crash), it leaves a SWP file. Opening the original file in Vim later gives the option of recovery. Most of the time the recovered file is the same as the saved file, because I have a habit of saving often. Then Vim says:

```
Recovery completed. Buffer contents equals file contents. 
You may want to delete the .swp file now.
```

Well, of course I want to delete the .swp file now!

**How can I get Vim to always delete the SWP file automatically in this case?**

There seems to be no built-in setting to do this, so I'm looking for an appropriate autocommand event.

One way I found is to `:e #` after the message, which causes the swap-exists options to appear again, then I can "Delete It". But I shouldn't really have to do those extra steps each time.

Comment: Thanks! I found your `:e #` trick is, albeit not ideal, but still more useful than the current answer below. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Note: you haven’t said which operating system you’re using. The following works with a Unix shell but if running Windows, you could download a bare-bones Cygwin or some other shell.

I used to do the same as you, run `:e` to re-open the same file to get the option to delete the recovery file.  After a crash or unexpected computer restart, I clean up all the remnant Vim recovery files by running `vim -r` on the swap files and letting the recovery proceed.

#### When files have *not* changed

If the files haven’t changed, I want to delete the recovery file immediately.  It would be great if Vim could do this automatically but unfortunately, it doesn’t.

#### When files have changed

If the files have changed, I run the `DiffOrig` command to compare the differences between the original and the recovered versions. If I’m happy with the changes from the recovery file, I exit by saving the files with the `:x` command. If not, I discard the recovered changes by quitting with `:q!`.  If the recovery file isn’t associated with a saved file, e.g, `.swp`, I usually use the `:w filename` to save the recovered buffer to a file with a filename.

#### DiffOrig helper

I added the [DiffOrig](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html#:DiffOrig) command to my `.vimrc` so that it’s always available.

```
command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r # | 0d_ | diffthis | wincmd p | diffthis
```

#### Shell script

I run the following script in my shell to find every swap-file in the current directory tree. Each swap-file is then used to open Vim in *“recovery mode”* and is then deleted after Vim is closed.

```bash
find . -type f -name '.*.sw?' -exec vim -r "{}" -c DiffOrig \; -exec rm -iv "{}" \;
```

The `rm -i` option requires confirmation (`y`) to delete the file.  If you’re more confident and want to speed up the process, this can be omitted.